# Ways of analyzing frequency of visits

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Suppose that there is a store with sections and we need to draw conclusions from a sample on the frequency of visits to the sections. Do not worry about how the sample was collected. Also, we are not interested in generalizing to population.

The data that we have is laid out in the following way:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
           & \text{Section } 1 & \text{Section } 2 & \text{Section } 3 & \cdots & \text{Section } n \\
\text{Customer } 1 & a_{1,1}      & a_{1,2}      & a_{1,3}      &     & a_{1,n}      \\
\text{Customer } 2 & a_{2,1}      & a_{2,2}      & a_{2,3}      &     & a_{2,n}      \\
\text{Customer } 3 & a_{3,1}      & a_{3,2}      & a_{3,3}      &     & a_{3,n}      \\
\vdots &           &           &           &     &           \\
\text{Customer } m & a_{m,1}      & a_{m,2}      & a_{m,3}      &     & a_{m,n}
\end{array}
$$

where $a_{i,j}$ is the number of times that the customer $i$ visited the section $j$.

Every customer was asked to provide how many times he visited the sections within the same period of time.

To give an example, here is how a store with 3 sections and 3 customers was visited.

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
           & \text{Section } 1 & \text{Section } 2 & \text{Section } 3 \\
\text{Customer } 1 & 1      & 3      & 2      \\
\text{Customer } 2 & 2      & 2      & 4      \\
\text{Customer } 3 & 0      & 1      & 1
\end{array}
$$

Given that data I would be tempted to say that section 3 is the most visited section, followed by section 2, and finally section 1. We can say that section 1 had 1 + 2 + 0 = 3 visits, section 2 had 3 + 2 + 1 = 6 visits, and section 3 had 2 + 4 + 1 = 7 visits. 16 visits were done in total. So in this case, section 1 was visited 3 / 16 = 0.1875 times, section 2 was visited 6 / 16 = 0.375 times, and section 3 was visited 7 / 16 = 0.4375 times.

However, if a customer goes a lot to the store but visits each section with the same frequency, the previous reasoning would lead to erroneous conclusions:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
           & \text{Section 1} & \text{Section 2} & \text{Section 3} \\
\text{Customer 1} & 10      & 30      & 20      \\
\text{Customer 2} & 2      & 2      & 4      \\
\text{Customer 3} & 0      & 1      & 1
\end{array}
$$

Section 1 had 12 visits, section 2 had 33 visits, and section 3 had 25 visits. 70 visits total. Now section 2 is the most visited, followed by section 3, and finally by section 1.

The analysis should have shown that section 3 is the most visited section, followed by section 2, and finally section 1. This means that the above approach is fragile. I suspect that the reason is that we have an outlier and the mean is sensitive to outliers.

1. Does it make sense to lay out the data in this way?
2. Can we say that the columns (Section 1, Section 2, Section 3, ..., Section n) are the variables (they could be renamed to "Visits to section"), and that the rows are the observations?
3. What is a good approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: Welcome to our site. None of your conclusions can be considered "erroneous," because they simply describe the data and they do so correctly.  You seem to want to make statistical inferences despite having stated that's not what you're doing--and it's that underlying indecision that's getting you into trouble.  I'm afraid I just cannot detect any problem at all here.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. You are right; maybe my approach makes sense and I am looking for something more elaborated for a simple problem. In any case, I am also looking to validate the initial approach, even though is simple, and the fact that it makes sense to you (and to @amandeep-jiddewar) gives me some confidence.

That said, I did some progress and it looks like what I am trying to achieve is called "Test of homogeneity", and chi-square is used. Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/test-if-differences-between-frequencies-is-significant.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose that there is a store with sections and we need to draw conclusions from a sample on the frequency of visits to the sections. Do not worry about how the sample was collected. Also, we are not interested in generalizing to population.
>
> Every customer was asked to provide how many times he visited the sections within the same period of time.
>
> However, if a customer goes a lot to the store but visits each section with the same frequency, the previous reasoning would lead to erroneous conclusions.
>
> This means that the above approach is fragile. I suspect that the reason is that we have an outlier and the mean is sensitive to outliers.
>
> 1. Does it make sense to lay out the data in this way?
> 2. Can we say that the columns (Section 1, Section 2, Section 3, ..., Section n) are the variables (they could be renamed to "Visits to section"), and that the rows are the observations?
> 3. What is a good approach to tackle this problem?

The easiest solution is to feed your CCTV footage to one of the many cloud based services.

No relying on customer participation and accuracy of the survey they fill out.

You can put popular items in direct view but some distance from the door to encourage a flow through the store and make unused areas better utilized. This avoids wasting high traffic areas with low profit items.

The cloud service will create a heat map that instantly and continuously shows the results.

[image: Customer Heat Map]

Some of the useful features of the Retail Analytics Solution are:

1. People Counting: Gauge the number of customers in store in different times of the day or different days of the week
2. Heat Map: Identify which areas of the store attract the highest number of customers or keep customer lingering for longer
3. Pathmap: Map out the directions and pathways that consumers tend to take inside a store
4. Multi-store comparison: Compare people count, heat map, pathmap and many other functions in different stores for devising effective product display or in-store promotion strategies across different stores

Cloud-based user-friendly customised analytic reports, complete with visual insights for easy understanding, are generated for clients. The reports can be accessed via mobile and smart devices anytime anywhere.

The article: "[Here’s What Brick-And-Mortar Stores See When They Track You](https://www.fastcompany.com/3015060/heres-what-brick-and-mortar-stores-see-when-they-track-you)" explains that some retailers combine customer WiFi information with CCTV to track individuals and provide more sophisticated results.

[image: Advanced Heat Maps]

Comment: Do not get me wrong, Rob, your answer is great, I had a fun time reading it!, but the store was just an analogy that I used. This problem can be generalized and converted into an abstract problem.

Comment: It wasn't clear enough that it was an analogy. If instead you wanted to check out whom goes where on a football field, or analyze vehicular traffic a similar theory applies. Relying on customers to voluntarily fill out a survey accurately has its own set of problems. Dividing a space into an even grid can also be problematic. If you could use less of an analogy and more of a few specific cases a better and more useful  answer could be forthcoming. If we have to guess what you really want I suppose you can decide how applicable the answers are to whatever your actual intended u
sage is.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you can do some manipulations on data. The problem can be solved by converting frequencies to ratio.

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
           & \text{Section 1} & \text{Section 2} & \text{Section 3} & \text{}\\
\text{Customer 1} & 10/60      & 30/60      & 20/60    &60/60  \\
\text{Customer 2} & 2/8      & 2/8      & 4/8      &8/8\\
\text{Customer 3} & 0/2      & 1/2      & 1/2     &2/2
\end{array}
$$

I don't know what this method is called, but to me logically makes sense to do this.

I understand little about Laplace correction. Out of curiosity, I know you don't like the idea of the mean of means. How about updating the number of visits with it's Laplace correction $${n + 1\over n + m + 2}$$ (n+m) = total number of visits in your case (sec1 + sec2 + sec3). I hear it is used in such examples(related to frequency) as you have provided in the question.

Comment: I believe we can, and it is something I considered and seems to help. But after doing it we would need a method to compare the different sections and decide which one is the most visited up to the least visited. And which method is that? Another mean calculation? Are not we doing the "mean of the means"?
So, to summarize, seems to help and this reasoning is quite intuitive, although I feel like I am looking for a more "elaborated" approach?

Comment: My 10 cent, The table lays information in intuitive and straightforward terms. I would not change the layout. As you already have figured that the mean is sensitive to outliers, you may think to use a median. But, I believe you previously have thought of these things as well, If not check please this link about how outliers-mean-median affect. - http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5601/notes/break.pdf

Comment: Interesting, Amandeep. It looks like you are still thinking through this, and I appreciate that.

I will dig about Laplace correction.